# Numerical minimum of a one-valued function

Tags: bugs, mathematical-optimization

**Bug introduced in 12.0** [CASE:4332003]

---

My problem is that the Kernel cannot finish computation and eats up memory when a simple constraint like `0 <= x <= 2` is specified in `FindMinimum`.

I have the function

```
f[x_] := 
  7/(5 Sqrt[5 Pi] + 2 Sqrt[11 Pi]) (2/7 Exp[-(x - 3)^2/11] + 5/7 Exp[-(x + 2)^2/5])
Plot[f[x], {x, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

I would like to find the local minimum near 1.95, and the two local maxima.
For the maxima, the following works:

```
FindMaximum[f[x], {x, 3}]
FindMaximum[f[x], {x, -3}]
```

For the minimum, however, the method seems to be highly sensitive to the starting value: with `FindMinimum[f[x], {x, 0}]` the minimum is found, but with `FindMinimum[f[x], {x, 1.9}]` or any other value close to the local minimum, I end up with a large value of `x` (and a value of `f[x]` close to 0, of course).

I tried to add a constraint, with `FindMinimum[{f[x], 1 <= x <= 2}, {x, 1.9}]`, but *Mathematica* takes forever, eats up gigabytes of memory, and I had to halt the execution.

I would like to know what I do wrong. There is the alternative of differentiating and using `FindRoot` which works well, but I think I am probably doing something wrong with `FindMinimum`. What should I do?

Comment: @m_goldberg Why you removed my Bug header? I've checked with previous versions and found that the problem is introduced in version 12.0.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov. I thought that a [tag:bugs] would be sufficient. If that kind of header is now in vogue, please restore it.

Comment: @m_goldberg The consensus about the bug header is here already for a while, please see "[Standard header for bugs-tagged posts, for easy searching](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1610/280)." and also discussion in comments there. I restore the header.

Comment: Reported to the support as [CASE:4332003].

Comment: This is quite fast `NMinimize[{f[x], 0 < x < 3}, x, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$Version

"12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)"

f[x_] := 7/(5 Sqrt[5 Pi] + 2 Sqrt[11 Pi]) (2/7 Exp[-(x - 3)^2/11] + 
     5/7 Exp[-(x + 2)^2/5]) // FullSimplify
```

For [`FindMinimum`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMinimum.html) use the [`WorkingPrecision`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision.html) option

```
min = FindMinimum[{f[x], 1 < x < 3}, {x, 2}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]

(* {0.064291094806372406402, {x -> 1.9667863700044219133}} *)

maxg = FindMaximum[f[x], {x, -3}]

(* {0.165184, {x -> -1.89931}} *)

maxl = FindMaximum[{f[x], 2 < x < 5}, {x, 7/2}]

(* {0.0647397, {x -> 2.66797}} *)

Plot[f[x], {x, -10, 10},
 PlotStyle -> LightGray,
 Epilog ->
  {AbsolutePointSize[3], Red, Point[{x, f[x]} /. {maxg, maxl}[[All, 2]]],
   Blue, Point[{x, f[x]} /. min[[2]]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm with `WorkingPrecision`. That's what I was missing, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

For most functions of a single variable using standard numerical functions, you can use [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve) (or [`NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve)) to find the zeros of the derivative of the function (within a specified interval), and then use the second derivative test to determine whether the zeros are minima or maxima (I will use [`NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve)):

```
sol = NSolve[f'[x] == 0 && -10 < x < 10 && f''[x] > 0, x]
```

> {{x -> 1.96679}}

The minimum value:

```
f[x] /. First @ sol
```

> 0.0642911

Answer (score 5):

> I tried to add a constraint, with `FindMinimum[{f[x], 1 <= x <= 2}, {x, 1.9}]`, but *Mathematica* takes forever, eats up gigabytes of memory, and I had to halt the execution.
>
> I think I am probably doing something wrong with `FindMinimum`. How should I do?

You are doing everything right, it is just a bug in `FindMinimum` introduced in version 12.0. Please report it to the support. Note that in version 11.3 it works as expected and returns the answer about **20 times faster** than version 12.0 with the workaround given below.

### A Workaround

The Documentation page "[Numerical Nonlinear Local Optimization](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationLocalNumerical.html#167853318)" says:

> Currently, the only method available for constrained optimization is the [interior point algorithm](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationLocalNumerical.html#interior%20point%20algorithm).

If we specify this method explicitly, *Mathematica* returns quickly using either of the two documented ways to specify the constraints:

```
FindMinimum[f[x], {x, 1.9, 0, 2}, Method -> "InteriorPoint"]
```

> ```
> {0.0642912, {x -> 1.96117}}
> ```

```
FindMinimum[{f[x], 0 <= x <= 2}, {x, 1.9}, Method -> "InteriorPoint"]
```

> ```
> {0.0642912, {x -> 1.96097}}
> ```

Note that the first method is slightly faster.